# Semantic UI font-awesome shows only square

Tags: css, font-awesome, semantic-ui

- Semantic UI js/css - 2.2.7
- jQuery v3.0.0
- Integrated with Magento 2.1.2

My icon `<i class="help icon"></i>` shows a square with the code F128 which correspond with the icon.help where it should actually show a help icon

On the same file, `<i class="dropdown icon"></i>` is showing a dropdown triangle. The css source is in correct path but why is one working and the other not?

[semantic css source](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/dist/semantic.min.css)

`i.icon {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0 0.25rem 0 0;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    width: 1.18em;
    }
    i.icon::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    }
    i.icon.dropdown:before,i.icon.triangle.down:before{
    content:"\f0d7
    }
    i.icon.help:before{
    content:"\f059
    }`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icon is most probably defined by the following selector:

```
.icon.help {}
```

not (Doesn't look like a dropdown icon defined in your css like so)

```
.icon.dropdown {}
```

If you must use the dropdown class here; you can try:

```
<i class="dropdown help icon"></i>
```

However keep in mind adding these classes may affect/override the look and feel of the "dropdown" class.

Comment: hmm I am not really sure about this explanation, and it doesn't work when I change the class, it is still displaying  a square with the code F128

Comment: can you post the css for the classes... ".icon", ".help" and ".dropdown"? together with the ::before/::after styles